# Why are thread locks resources?

Tags: multithreading, locking

I recently read that thread locks are system resources, therefore they have to be properly released "just like memory". I realised I wasn't really aware of this.

Can someone offer some further elaboration on this fact or point to a good reference? More specifically: how can I think about the implementation of locks at a deeper system level?  What are the possible consequences of leaking locks? Is there a maximum number of locks available in the system?

Comment: Always document what operating system you use when you ask about implementation details.

Answer (score 0):

All that means is that you have to be careful that anything you lock gets released, similar to how you would be careful to close network connections or files or graphic device contexts or whatever. If you write code that is not careful about that, then you risk having the program deadlock or be unable to progress when it can't get access to something that's locked (because the point of locking is to make sure multiple threads can access something safely, so if one thread leaves something locked other threads that need to access it are shut out).

The program will have severe performance issues a long time before it runs out of physical locks, so typically you shouldn't have to worry about the number of available locks.